# transparent background images to find where

Tags: html, css, image

sorry to ask this question guys but i am really in help..
i found a lot but didn't find out..
i want to know where i can found out such transparent images of different kinds

[image: Transparent Background Styles]

```
<div>
  <span>no use code</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>no use code</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>no use code</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>no use code</span>
</div>
```

`Note` : above code is of no use, i just need to ask the websites to find out such images`

Comment: And the problem its? Can you elaborate your question? Its this relate to code at all?

Comment: This is maybe the best/worst question I have ever seen...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `opacity` property of CSS to add transparency to any image like this:

```css
#transparent {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
#transparent-2 {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />

<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" id="transparent" />

<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-640-480-7.jpg" width="350px" />

<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-640-480-7.jpg" width="350px" id="transparent-2" />
```